# Wordpress 4.5.2 Media library/featured image issues

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, media, wordpress-featured-image

my media library is not working correctly, on grid view display, the circle animation is just spinning forever - [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuesP.jpg)
In a list preview it show that i uploaded it [Preview2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRDhr.jpg) , but as you can it doesn't show thumbnail. When i try to upload image on a featured image i get this error "an error occurred in the upload. please try again later".

- I tried to disable plugins on by one
- Disabled theme and switched to default
- Changed hosting provider
- I tried upload also very small images, so it isn't a problem with image size/dimensions

So i started a new fresh wordpress site on my localhost with the same database and i looks like my database causing this trouble. I might be wrong, but i think because of it.

With a new fresh database media library is working perfectly. What then should i do? If want to use fresh database, then i almost have to recreate my site...

Comment: Check your server settings if you have anything that blocks admin-ajax.php. If you switch to list view, you'll be able to see your images. Also check the inspector Network tab, select XHR and see what ajax returns. Also enable debugging in `wp-config.php` and see if any error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

In htaccess after "# END WordPress” add...

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html
```

Replacing username with the cpanel username for the account
Note there is no / on the end

Then add a file called php.ini to the public_html folder with the following in it

```
memory_limit = 512M
extension=imagick.so
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```

That resolved it for our hosting customers

Comment: i did everything like you said, now i tried to open website and i get this error http://prntscr.com/b3a50b. "suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html" this line is causing the error. Obviously i changed the username to my cpanel username as u mentioned

Comment: Your hosting company probably has a different configuration. Remove that line from htaccess and add  php_value memory_limit 64M Directly in htaccess. If that doesn't work try using define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M'); in wpconfig.php

Answer (score 0):

the problem was i saved a letter "S" before open tag in my wp-config file. I spended so much time for looking any solution possible, for that small mistake, anyways thank you for trying me help